# prove this by binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations

Prove that by binomial theorem :

$\dbinom{6}{0}+\dbinom{6}{2}+\dbinom{6}{4}+\dbinom{6}{6}=\dbinom{6}{1}+\dbinom{6}{3}+\dbinom{6}{5}$

I started to prove it by moving the right side to the left :

$\dbinom{6}{0}+\dbinom{6}{2}+\dbinom{6}{4}+\dbinom{6}{6}-\dbinom{6}{1}-\dbinom{6}{3}-\dbinom{6}{5}=0$

it should be done by the binomial coefficient ...?....
how ??

*thanks in advance*

Comment: i would calculate this directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr1^{n-r}(-1)^r=\sum_{r=0}^{2r\le n}\binom n{2r}-\sum_{r=0}^{2r+1\le n}\binom n{2r+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The number of subsets of even cardinality= The number of subsets with odd cardinality.

Comment: Your answer is acceptable, but the other answer follows the sentence "it should be done by the binomial coefficient" and proves the equation "by binomial theorem".